# Anaconda can't find pygtk

Tags: python, import, module, gtk, anaconda

Running osx, with anaconda distribution...I have imported the module `pygtk` with:

`conda install -c vgauthier pygtk=2.24.0` as found [here](https://anaconda.org/vgauthier/pygtk).  Pygtk is reflected in `conda list`, which returns:

```
...
pygments                  2.2.0                    py27_0
pygobject                 3.10.0                   py27_1    vgauthier
pygtk                     2.24.0                   py27_1    vgauthier
pyopenssl                 16.2.0                   py27_0
...
```

However, the import will fail, e.g., in `ipython`:

```
In [1]: import pygtk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f8a9c750c915> in <module>()
----> 1 import pygtk

ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

Comment: Did you check if the import works in a standard python console? (Just to make sure that you aren't accidentally using multiple (differen) python versions)

Comment: @FabianN. yes, same result as posted here (and confirmed its calling the anaconda python executable).

Comment: Then my next suggestion would be to try one of the other package providers, see here for a list: https://charmie11.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/pygtk-installation-using-anaconda/ nvm they aren't online anymore...

Comment: @FabianN The one installed appears to be the only macos 64bit module available.

Comment: Ah sry just found that out too. Well, other than the module beeing available under another name (like the progressbar2 module that is actually imported as 'progressbar') ... I'm out of ideas, looks like you have to wait for someone with more in depth knowledge...

Comment: On a side note, pygtk is dead so you probably want pygobject.

Comment: @TingPing pygtk is a dependency for a backend... is pygobject a replacement?

Comment: No, but whatever depends upon pygtk should be updated or is probably a dead project itself.

Comment: @TingPing ok, this is good info.  FWIW, I was testing out graphics backends (I don't remember which one specifically).